How can I upload/send an image to multi-modal LLMs like Google's Gemini-Flash using Langchain JS?
I've been digging in the Langchain documentation (and type definitions) and even asked LLMs how I can upload or send an image to multi-modal LLMS, but I haven't found anything.
This is my current code:
import { ChatGoogleGenerativeAI } from "@langchain/google-genai";

  const model = new ChatGoogleGenerativeAI({
    model: "gemini-1.5-flash",
    apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
  });

  // Batch and stream are also supported
  const res = await model.invoke(
    [["system", "What's the tallest building of the world?"]],
    {}
  );

I know for instance that Google's node SDK does support it:
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash" });

const prompt = "Does this look store-bought or homemade?";
const image = {
  inlineData: {
    data: Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync("cookie.png")).toString("base64"),
    mimeType: "image/png",
  },
};

const result = await model.generateContent([prompt, image]);
console.log(result.response.text());

But I don't know how to format this correctly so I can send it using Langchain.
Any ideas?
